# A proper way to cook Mi Goreng noodles?

Tags: noodles

I've purchased a 30 pack box of these delicious noodles and I'd like advice on how to cook them **properly**. From past experiences, I've either used too much water which made them soggy and very soft which doesn't retain the Thai flavor. So any advice would be nice (how much water to use, drain the water out afterwards, cook for how long, temperature etc). Help?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not too much water that makes them soggy, it's cooking them for too long *in* the water. Thin noodles are virtually done as soon as they break out of their dry, tablet shape. As soon as this happens, take a noodle out and test it. Remember that cooking will continue even after you drain the noodles.

You should drain the noodles well in a colander. If you are planning on stir frying the noodles, you need to first wash the starch off them - run the cold water tap over them and circulate it through the noodles with your hand (carefully, they might still be hot in the middle). They then need to be dried as much possible - spread them out on a board, pat with paper towel, and leave for ten minutes or so before stir frying (preferably in an empty wok - cook the rest of the stir fry first, then empty it, cook the noodles, and re-add the meat etc.)

Comment: Thanks, what about the seasoning that they provide? When should I add them?

Comment: It should tell you on the packet.

Answer (score 13):

@ElendilTheTall's answer would probably make some pretty badass Mi Goreng, but the whole point of packet Mi Goreng is to be a 2 minute meal in the least work possible.

The way I make Mi Goreng is to cook the noodles in a small pot until they're just cooked (a little firmer than you prefer to eat them). 
Quickly drain them, throw them back in the same pot and add all the seasonings except the fried onion.
Put the pot back on the hot briefly (or just use the residual heat from the element) and stir the noodles all around. Basically stir frying them within the pot.
Tip them out into a bowl and add the fried onion sachet (or just eat from the pot).

This always works pretty well for me, I get a result that isn't too far in consistency from the real thing.

PS. Mi Goreng are Indonesian, not Thai :)

Comment: Oops, did I write Thai? I'd give you plus one but I don't have enough reputation... thanks for the seasoning tip!

Answer (score 4):

I know this is quite an old thread, but Mi Goreng never gets old so here's my method:

Empty the seasonings (all of them) on to a plate, add the noodles to boiling water and about half way through cooking (about a minute or two) add a cracked egg. By the time the noodles are cooked (which is as soon as they lose their wriggly shape) the egg is also cooked with the yolk still nice and runny. Drain everything in a colander and transfer to the plate. Mix everything together, the egg will break and the yolk will coat everything, making it a bit saucier. It's sooooo yummy and easy :)

Answer (score 0):

This is his how my wife does it: use as little water as possible (just enough for the broken up noodles to *swim in*) and throw in the dry spices in with the noodles. Keep watching the pot. As soon as the noodles are done take them out quickly, you don't want them to overcook. Mix in the liquid ingredients and serve immediately.

Comment: Should I keep the heat on high the entire time? 4 packets on I still find myself _slightly_ overcooking them, would turning the heat down to medium help?

Comment: I've never tried that actually. I believe the trick is taking them out *just* before they are done, since they will continue to cook with the residual heat.

Answer (score 0):

heres another technique I use: I use 6 or 7 mi goreng noodles for this :)

1. Boil water about half way, or you can boil the water in kettle then add in pot easier..
2. Then add all the seasonings to the pot, mixing the flavours every time you keep adding them so they won't stick to the bottom.
3. Immediately after you add the flavours and mix all together you add the noodles in so the flavour can sink into the noodles.
4. But make sure you don't over cook it let the water sink in with the noodles and mix all together once all the noodles are cooked turn off the cooking and its ready to be served and woolah you got nice hot migoreng noodles with abit of its delicious hot soup with it too...mmmmmmm...

Answer (score 0):

My favorite way (and I think the best way) to prepare these noodles is to first boil the noodles for just over a minute so they're about al dente. Then, I strain the noodles and toss them in a heated saute pan with about 2 tsp vegetable oil. I stir fry the noodles for around 30 seconds to lose any excess water. Then, I add in all the seasonings except for the fried onions and stir fry it into the noodle for another minute. Finally, I transfer my noodles to a bowl and garnish with the fried onions. The noodles are still chewy with some crispy bits so they really taste like a great fried noodle.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I do it:

1. Put 1-2 (or however many you want) noodle bricks into a pot.
2. Put some boiling water from your kettle/hot water jug into the pot until it covers the noodles.
3. Cook them on high. Make sure you add **all** the seasonings, but you don't have to use the onion, oil or hot sauce.
4. When they look soft, crack 1 (or however many you want) eggs into the pot. Stir the eggs until they're scrambled/"broken."
   Optional: Add vegetables, meat, etc.
5. (If you want, drain the water now) Put the noodles into your bowl, or just eat from the pot.

Also, the perfect pairing is a cup of miso soup! I use some that comes in a packet.

Answer (score 0):

Put noodles in a bowl, cover with boiling water and cover bowl with lid or cling wrap. Stand for 3 mins. Drain and add seasoning. No “cooking” required and only uses one dish !

Answer (score -3):

Its 3 minutes and you use no water (except for cooking the noodles) mix spices first except the dried onion then drain mix sprinkle serve :-)

Comment: "Use no water (except for cooking the noodles)" is not very helpful advice - the OP was trying to figure out how much water to use to cook the noodles.